# Vagrant: Queues in laravel homestead

Tags: php, laravel, queue, vagrant

I'm using laravel's homestead on my local environnement and I use Queue system to send mail. I have to run `php artisan queue:listen` if I want to test mail

When I restart my computer (and vagrant), I must type again `vagrant ssh` then `php artisan queue:listen`. It's ok for me but I don't work alone, and I want to simplify the process: a developer has just to open his computer, then type `vagrant up`.

How can I configure vagrant/homestead to always run laravel's queue listener on start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your vagrants config file;

```
$script = <<SCRIPT
vagrant ssh & php artisan queue:listen
date > /etc/vagrant_provisioned_at
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer, I will test it ASAP and validate your answer if it's ok